# cfquery param on query containing if statment

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery

How do you use cfqueryparam on this line of code?

```
SET mailing_list = <CFIF IsDefined("FORM.mailing_list")>#FORM.mailing_list#<CFELSE>0</CFIF>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would just use two separate cfqueryparam's

```
SET mailing_list = 
<cfif StructKeyExists(form,'mailing_lis't)>
  <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value "#FORM.mailing_list#" />
<cfelse>
  0
</cfif>
```

Comment: This is much cleaner and more readable than the other examples.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
SET mailing_list = <CFIF IsDefined("FORM.mailing_list")>
    <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.mailing_list#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
<CFELSE>
    0
</CFIF>
```

On recent CFML engines, you can use the ternary conditional operator:

```
SET mailing_list = <cfqueryparam value="#IsDefined("FORM.mailing_list") ? FORM.mailing_list : 0#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
```

(Though that is arguably less readable here.)

Best way is most likely to param it above your query and avoid any if altogether...

```
<cfparam name="Form.mailing_list" default="0" />

...

SET mailing_list = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.mailing_list#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
```

Comment: Second method also means that only one query goes to the db to be parsed. Only the value of the bind variable would change.

Comment: I like the second method as well - and I would add a "val()" as in *value="#val(form.mailing_list)#"* to insure that a non numeric character does cause an error to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `IIF` for short IF statements:

```
SET mailing_list = <cfqueryparam value="#iif(IsDefined("form.mailing_list"), form.mailing_list, 0)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
```

Otherwise I prefer the "long and clean" way:

```
<CFIF IsDefined("FORM.mailing_list")>
   SET mailing_list = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.mailing_list#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
<CFELSE>
   SET mailing_list = <cfqueryparam value="0" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
</CFIF>
```

Comment: Do not forget to wrap the second condition in a `de()` to avoid an error if the form field does not exist.